# A lambda compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I wrote the following lambda expression in my code:

```
auto fnd_rpt_chrs = [&] (string::iterator& iter_arg) {
for(auto iter = iter_arg + 1; iter !=  s2.end(); ++iter){
if(*iter == *iter_arg)
return true;
}
return false;
};
```

Elsewhere, I invoke the lambda in the following manner:

```
void some_function(string const& s2){
auto iter = s2.begin();
fnd_rpt_chrs(iter);
}
```

For the above, I get the following compilation error:

> no known conversion from 'std::__1::__wrap_iter' to
>   'string::iterator &' (aka '__wrap_iter &') for 1st argument

Can someone point out what am I missing here?

TIA

Vinod

Comment: `const_iterator` vs `iterator`.

Comment: unless `s2` is global you better pass it to lambda as argument

Comment: @Jarod42 can you please modify the code to show what you imply? I tried changing the lambda argument type string::iterator const& but that does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mismatch between `iterator` and `const_iterator` (in addition, iterator can be passed by value), you might change your lambda to:

```
auto fnd_rpt_chrs = [&] (string::const_iterator iter_arg) {
    for (auto iter = iter_arg + 1; iter != s2.end(); ++iter){
        if(*iter == *iter_arg)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```